# Bad grade in thesis, because of not elaborate report , but the work graded qualitatively impressive by technical supervisor

Tags: thesis, masters, germany

I am in this weird dilemma , where I got a low grade on my masters thesis in robotics because of my inability to submit an elaborate report , because of approaching deadline , I was barely able to submit minimal version. One of my supervisor is from the lab and is expert in the field and I did research under him on an ambitious project. Other is to officiate the grading as a full professor from the department .The expert supervisor, has rated the work to be very impressive qualitatively at masters level  , but the 2nd supervisor(non related field ) insisted on giving a poor grade because of poor draft. My thesis grade suffered and fall to 2.7(on German grade) , what will be the advisable route for me to compensate for the poor grade and somehow, show the future employers or academics that it does not represent the qualitative aspect of my thesis work done in the lab.

Comment: Difficult to say. Do you have oral exams? The problem is that the project indicates excellent technical skills (it seems), but either bad writing or timekeeping skills. Unfortunately, the mark reflects the combination, it seems. Maybe get a reference from the positive marker.

Comment: Thanks , this is what , I intend to do. I have also asked for him, so that , we can publish .

Comment: I don't know if its the same at your university, but where I am, the bachelors thesis is marked 80% on the  written thesis itself, and 20% on the technical work of the research. You should check if this is the case for you, and if so, were you made aware of this (is it in a syllabus document you were provided with etc). If not, you should ask how the technical proficiency feeds into your grade, according the official grading rubric.

Comment: Is the 2.7 the grade for your thesis or the grade for MSc as a whole? The thesis often has surprisingly low impact on the overall grade.

Comment: 2.7 in thesis , my master aggregate is 2.4

Answer (score 13):

> because of approaching deadline

Part of your assessment on most projects, whether in school or the rest of life, includes the ability to complete the work by a deadline or in an otherwise efficient time frame.

You make it sound like this is some mysterious deadline coming from an unknown source, but it was probably well known to you or should have been from the start.

As others have recommended, you should try to publish the best version of the work possible and rely on letters of recommendation to explain your abilities. Most importantly, though, you'll want to learn to take responsibility for completion of your work going forward.

Comment: Sure , I had done lot of self reflection , post this , along with Time scheduling , being more realistic , Latex and Inkscape are the things i need to improve from here.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably little you can do unless you can convince the supportive advisor to have a conversation with the other one to change the grade, if that is even possible.

Beyond that, the record is what it is and the thesis is what it is.

To go further you have the option, of course, of choosing who writes letters of recommendation for you and the option of explaining that deadlines interfered with providing a better product. There are no guarantees, but you do what you can with what you have.

And if you need to improve your time management or writing skills you can work on that.

Comment: thanks for suggestion , this bad thesis submission have highlighted my poor scientific draft preparation skills and I need to work a lot on these moving forward.